# Vector Graphics and Quartz 2D iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, graphics, vector

I have created and published to the Apple Store a simple text based iPhone App that has some images, but doesn't have any real "motion and pizzazz" to it. Is it simple enough to add some vector Graphics or is it a difficult process to learn? I've heard that Quartz 2D has the capability, but I have a "day job" and I'm wondering how much time it takes to learn the product or is there a group or individual that does "paid for" "small project" programming?

Answer (score 0):

Animations are probably the ticket.  You don't need to use low-level quartz stuff, just use the UIView animations.  Ray Wenderlich has a good overview  [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial) and you can google plenty of others.